# flask sqlalchemy pass Database name as string

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am developing a [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) app that communicate with SQL through [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

I have a simple question that I found no answer looking online, how can I pass a `database_name` through a `str()` to the request. As example:

```py
    row_id = 1

    ### normal call
    row = User.query.filter_by(id = row_id).first_or_404()

    ### what I'd like to achieve
    database_name = User
    row = database_name.query.filter_by(id = row_id).first_or_404()
```

Of course I am getting

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'query'

but I'd like to know if there's a safe way to achieve this.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the built in exec()

Code:

database_name = “User”
row = exec(database_name + “.query.filter_by(id = row_id”).first_or_404())

Comment: is it safe in a production environment where the `database_name` is passed by the request string and the function may be `delete()` ?

Comment: You could have a verification step in which you test whether the input is a valid database_name

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided in the snippet above should work, but it sounds like what you *want* is to be able to resolve the `User` model from the `'User'` string.

There is nothing baked into sqlalchemy to achieve this; the `query` method requires the actual model class.

However, that doesn't mean it's not possible. My team solves similar problems by registering the model name to the class in a registry. Here is a very simplistic version of this. In production code you might want to be more careful about making sure model_name_registry is a singleton instance of a class, and that you aren't double-registering any model names, etc.

```py
model_name_registry = {}

# Create a decorator to automatically register model names to the class
def register_class_name(cls_):
    model_name_registry[cls_.__name__] = cls_

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return cls_(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner


# Decorate the classes you want to refer to by string
@register_class_name
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table_name'
    # . . .
```

Then, you can do:

```py
model = model_name_registry['User']
model.query(...)
```

Comment: That worked, the problem is that I have another call to automatically get column names `column_names = User.__table__.columns.keys()` and now it gives the error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__table__'`